# Why is the sentence: "There is not anything in the box" wrong?

Tags: word-choice

I know the proper way to write that is "There isn't anything in the box" but why? I had the impression that isn't was just an abbreviation for "is not"

Comment: Actually, the sentence in your title is not grammatically incorrect. Why did you think it is? At most, it sounds a bit odd, since contractions are generally used when speaking, and a construction with a negative pronoun "There is nothing" would generally be used when writing.

Comment: half full, half empty to me ?

Comment: *There isn't anything in the box* means exactly the same as *There is not anything in the box* but the *…is not…* option is less likely in speech…